# Are there other optimum way to check falsy value if it is String?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is data which it may equals any type(*Object, String, Array, ...*) in my example.

But, sometimes data returns string falsy value(like `"false"`, `"undefined"`, `"0"`, `"null"`). It should return false from condition.

```
var Helper = {
  isEmpty: function(data){
      return !data || data === "false" || data === "null" || data === "undefined" || data === "0" || data === "NaN";
  }
}
console.log(Helper.isEmpty("false"));//true
console.log(Helper.isEmpty("null"));//true
//...
```

Are there another optimum way? Any ideas?

Comment: Use `==` instead of `===`

Comment: @Jackson. Are you saying `data == false`. good idea

Comment: `!!String(data).replace(/((null)|(false)|(0)|(undefined))/g,"")`

Comment: `!!String(data).replace(/null|false|undefined|0|NaN/,"");` would be more accurate and shorter. There's no need for all those capture groups that you aren't using the results of. @dandavis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED:** I find some solutions:

**1)** It is shorter and smarter way: `/false|NaN|undefined|0|null/.test(data);`

```js
   var Helper = {
        isEmpty: function (data) {
            return /false|NaN|undefined|0|null/.test(data);
        }
    };
    console.log(Helper.isEmpty("false"));//true
    console.log(Helper.isEmpty(false));//true
    console.log(Helper.isEmpty("null"));//true
    console.log(Helper.isEmpty("test"));//false
    //...
```

**2)** Or, check it through object:

```js
var Helper = {
  isEmpty: function(data){
      return !!{false:1, null:1, undefined:1, NaN:1, 0:1}[data] || !data;
  }
}
console.log(Helper.isEmpty("false"));//true
console.log(Helper.isEmpty("null"));//true
//...
```

Comment: while this does work, any coworker who has to read and maintain your code will not like you

Comment: is there any bad logic. Please, explain me, why?

Comment: It's no very readable imho. In TinyGiant's answer it's obvious what the function does on the first look, here not so much

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.indexOf()` to search an array for the specified value, if the value is not in the array then the returned value will be -1.

```js
var Helper = {
  isEmpty: function(data){
    return data ? ["false","null","undefined","0","NaN"].indexOf(data) !== -1 : true;
  }
}

function test(a) {
  for(var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) console.log(a[i] + ' isEmpty: ' + Helper.isEmpty(a[i]));
}

test([false,'false','null','undefined','0','NaN','Hello World!']);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, especially for `test([])`